# remote launch $find resolves to local machine

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm launching some nodes in a remote machine, everything works fine except the parameters passed using the $find macro are being resolved locally and not to the remote machine path. The parameters are loaded to the parameter server based on the local files, and filenames parameters became with the wrong path.

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67573/remote-launch-$find-resolves-to-local-machine/) by [rlklaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/3974/rlklaser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-17**:
What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As documented in the [$find macro](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) all invocations of $find are resolved locally.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0